# Travis does not push docker image to hub

Tags: docker, travis-ci

As in title, Travis does not want to push docker image to docker hub after successfully test passing? What is wrong? I have already set env variabales `DOCKER_PASSWORD and DOCKER_USERNAME`. Any ideas?

```
language: python
sudo: required
services: 
  - docker

script:
  - docker-compose run web python manage.py test

after_success:
  - echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin
  - docker build -t maciejwojtkowiak/todo . 
  - docker push maciejwojtkowiak/todo .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.` at the end of the docker push

Comment: Oh sir  I have spent one hour to solve it and it was just ','  :D